# how to submit form only if validation is success

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

i try to validate the form before submitting the request.
i am using jquery validation

i am expecting when page finish load, the form will auto submit, and i will see "Loading" in the div.
but nothing happen
here is my code. but seems it is not working..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function submitForm() {
        $('#SearchForm').validate({
            errorLabelContainer: "#ErrorLabel",
            rules: {
                instrument: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 10
                }
            },
            messages: {
                maxlength: "Must no longer than 10 characters",
                required: "Must not be empty"
            },

            submitHandler: function () { $('#SearchForm').submit(); }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#SearchForm').submit(function () {
            $('#DivToUpdate').text('Loading ...');
        });
        submitForm();
    });
</script>
```

ll

Comment: use return true/false in your method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Made a small **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/CRfuZ/

2 things: try putting `invalidHandler` and pass `form` to  the `submitHandler`

In the demo above if you will enter more then `maxlenght 10` the halbert in `invalidHandler` will capture it.

Rest feel free to play around with the demo.

This will help hopefully :)

link: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate

**COde**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#form").validate({
        debug: false,
        focusInvalid: false,
        onfocusout: false,
        onkeyup: false,
        onclick: false,
        rules: {
            instrument: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 10
            },
        },
        messages: {
            maxlength: "Must no longer than 10 characters",
            required: "Must not be empty"
        },
        success: function(label) {
            alert('succes:' + label);
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert('start submitHandler');
            postContent('test');
            alert('end submitHandler');
        },
        invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
            alert('invalidHandler');
        },
    });
});


function postContent(postData) {
    alert('postcontent: ' + postData);

}


​
```

Answer (score 1):

Using code written below may solve your problem ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ( $ ) {
            var $theForm = $( 'form' );
        $( '#DivToUpdate' ).text( 'Loading ...' );
        $theForm.validate({
            rules: {
                instrument : {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 10
                }
            }, messages: {
                maxlength : "Must no longer than 10 characters",
                required : "Must not be empty"
            }
        });
        if( $theForm.valid() ) {
            $theForm.submit(); //submitting the form
        }
    });
</script>
```

You're not supposed to use `submitHandler` generally ...

Added: Running example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rashid2538/R3Fk6/).