# Jquery Validate : if input has specific value : error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, validation

I tried to solve my problem for 6 hours.

I use the jQuery Validation plugin.

I have a form with a password input. If the password is wrong (an AJAX request tells me), another input has value 0.
If this input has no value, or value 0, I would like my form not to be submitted.

But it doesn't work and I can't explain why.

Here is my HTML :

```
<form method="post"  action="ajax/traitement.php"   id="form-durabilite" class="col-lg-12">
    <input type="text" id="switch" name="input_cache" value=""/>
    <input type="password" name="signature" id="sign"/>
    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" type="submit"value="Envoyer" />

</form>
```

And my jQuery :

```
$('#form-durabilite' ).validate({
    rules: {
        signature: {
            required:function(element) {
                return $('#switch').val() == 0 || $('#switch').val() == ''
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        signature: {
            required:'Votre mot de passe est obligatoire'
        }
    }
});
```

I have no message, nothing, like my rule does not exist !
What did I do bad?

Comment: If you are submitting your form with ajax then you can validate it on `beforeSubmit` function and `alert()` the error message

Comment: ` $('#switch')` where in the html code is this defined?

Comment: Here :   <input type="text" id="switch" name="input_cache" value=""/>

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression like this instead of writing function inside rules :

This [$.validator.addMethod] is common method for check input value as per given regular expression

```
 $.validator.addMethod("regx", function(value, element, regexpr) {
       var re = new RegExp(regexpr);
       var ret = re.test(value);
       return ret;
    });

$('#form-durabilite' ).validate({
    rules: {
        signature: {
            required:true,
            regx:"^[^0-9]{6}$" // Here you can give regular expression for validating you input values
        }
    },
    messages: {
        signature: {
            required:'Votre mot de passe est obligatoire',
            regx:'Le mot de passe n'est pas valide'
        }
    }
});
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [how to submit form only if validation is success](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10959728/3513687).

Add in **submitHandler** parameter as well with a *form.submit()*. This will trigger form-submit only when the jQuery validate is entirely truthy.

Please try this out.

Comment: Hi, thank for your answer. I did not precise it but I have a submit function :   submitHandler: function(form) { alert('formulaire validé'); return false; }. It doesn't work anymay.

Comment: Hey, I meant to do submitHandler: function(){ $("#form-durabilite").submit() }. Please try again.